# What is "Ext'd (LBA)" in fdisk output?

Tags: filesystems, partition

This is my partition table.  Output of fdisk -l

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   204796619   102398278+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       204796681   488375999   141789659+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       204796683   337911209    66557263+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6       337911273   488375999    75232363+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I need to understand the partition table especially /dev/sda2
which shows Ext'd (LBA).

Comment: Have you read at least the Wikipedia article about partition tables?

Answer (score 5):

The DOS partition table only has room for 4 entries, so to have more than 4 partitions, you can designate one of the 4 as an extended partition, then that partition can itself be subdivided into as many logical partitions as you want.  Logical partitions are numbered starting with 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here read these references:

**From wikipedia**

- [MBR - Master Boot Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)
- [GPT - GUID Partition Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)

**Comparison of MBR vs. GPT**

- [Windows GPT Disks – Is Bigger Really Better?](http://www.petri.co.il/gpt-vs-mbr-based-disks.htm)